# How to spool using SQLPlus

Tags: sqlplus

I am trying to spool using SQLPlus, but I am having difficulty.  Here is the text I am using:

```
spool MyText.txt;
```

The file `MyText.txt` does not yet exist.  Will it create the file for me?

I have tried spooling to a file that I've already created, but that doesn't work either.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `spool`ing to a file that does not exist will create it in your currnt running directory.

Comment: Thanks.  But why do I keep getting errors messages.  Every time I try to spoo, it says CANNOT create SPOOL file MyText.txt

Comment: You probably have no permissions to create a file in the current working directory